Kubernetes, tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I'm trying to install Kubernetes on my ubuntu virtual machine which is 24.04 LTS. While fetching the releaseKey I'm getting unable to get local issuer certificate. I'm sitting behind the corporate Zscaler firewall.
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.30/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
File '/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
                                                                                                                                                       More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

      curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
                                                                                establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
                                                                                                                                                           how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
              y
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Now, If i do the same thing in insecure fashion, like adding -k flag in the above command I'm able to get the releaseKey & sign it but while pulling the kubernetes core-components I'm getting the below error:
kubeadm config images pull
W1208 14:16:28.352329   25565 version.go:104] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
W1208 14:16:28.352504   25565 version.go:105] falling back to the local client version: v1.30.7
failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7": output: E1208 14:16:29.212801   25591 remote_image.go:180] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.30.7\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7"
time="2024-12-08T14:16:29Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.30.7\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.30.7\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
, error: exit status 1
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

What I've tried so far?
ensuring ca-certificates utility is there:
apt install ca-certificates

disabling apt's OCSP verification, and is not recommended
touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf \
&& echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }"

Exporting the zscaler certificate from any website (by clicking on the padlock & is usually in .pem) to my VM on the path /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/zscaler.crt & then running update-ca-certificate command.

I'm able to resolve this issue by getting the Root CA from my corporate IT team & placed it in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ & then finally ran update-ca-certificate it worked like a magic then.
